# How to use GPU enabled OpenCV with ROS Kinetic?

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic, rosrun, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to use CUDA enabled OpenCV with ROS. I have kinetic which already has one OpenCV 3.2 but it is not cuda enabled and also doesn't have extra modules of opencv_contrib. For this reason, I built a new OpenCV in /usr/local with CUDA and opencv_contrib enabled and I got this new OpenCV working.

Now I have been through most of the question for implementing custom OpenCV with ROS and somehow, I am able to compile (catkin_make) my package using with custom OpenCV but when I run it, with rosrun, it again uses kinetic opencv and shows cuda not enabled. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

P.S - I am able to use extra modules even with kinetic opencv also (It just worked by itself). Only that cuda part is not working for me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262683/how-to-use-gpu-enabled-opencv-with-ros-kinetic?/) by [naveenT1010](https://answers.ros.org/users/30447/naveent1010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-05-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got this thing working now. I followed this : [Similar Question](http://answers.ros.org/question/242376/having-trouble-using-cuda-enabled-opencv-with-kinetic/?answer=242935#post-id-242935)

The key was that I had to rebuild all other packages also which were dependent upon OpenCV (`vision_opencv` which has `cv_bridge`).  Also, in my cmakelist file, I have include all OpenCV packages and libraries for my project before the catkin packages. I dont know currently if it played a major role, but atleast its working now.

If the problem still persists, please check your `$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. They should have the `/usr/local` (where your custom OpenCV is present)  path before any of the ROS paths.

---

Originally posted by [naveenT1010](https://answers.ros.org/users/30447/naveent1010/) with karma: 63 on 2017-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2019-08-22**:
I am facing the same problem, I uninstalled opencv library and leave kinetic which already has OpenCV 3.3.1-dev.

how to run the code with GPU.

please help me